# Python 3 How to convert data in type list back to dict

Tags: python, json

How to convert the data in type list back to dict as below sample code. Thanks

```
[{
                        "type": "box",
                        "layout": "horizontal",
                        "margin": "xs",
                        "contents": [
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": "12/12/2019 time 15:00",
                                "size": "sm",
                                "weight": "bold"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": "Press",
                                "size": "sm",
                                "align": "end",
                                "weight": "bold",
                                "color": "#EE4C4C",
                                "action": {
                                    "type": "message",
                                    "label": "Click",
                                    "text": "to to this"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
```

so i try to convert back to str and remove "[" , "]" and convert back to dict but the result showing not support format when i bring this to json.dumps as below

```
"{'type': 'box', 'layout': 'horizontal', 'margin': 'xs', 'contents': [{'type': 'text', 'text': '12/12/2019 time 15:00', 'size': 'sm', 'weight': 'bold'}, {'type': 'text', 'text': 'Press', 'size': 'sm', 'align': 'end', 'weight': 'bold', 'color': '#EE4C4C', 'action': {'type': 'message', 'label': 'Click', 'text': 'to to this'}}]}"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What’s the problem here? Can’t you just use `json.load()`? That title also doesn’t make much sense. I’m voting to close this question as it is completely unclear what you’re asking, and there are already **many** seemingly similar questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be unpacking

```
print(type(*mylist))
# <class 'dict'>
```

If you want to do it using string manipulation, you can try this, but keep in mind the previous way is better as `evel` [is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

```
print(type(eval(str(l)[1:-1])))
```

Comment: I think it’s valid JSON, so I don’t really see why any of this would be necessary. In addition, I think it’s quite likely that OP’s data is in a file. It’s not a list in Python source code.